# Automatically start Jekyll on vagrant up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a Vagrant box setup the same as Github Pages, I've installed Jekyll and everything is great but the problem is that everytime I start the machine I have to type in the following command:

```
cd /vagrant && bundle exec jekyll serve --watch -P 4567 --force_polling
```

Is there any way that I can run that command after Vagrant mounted the shared folder /vagrant ? I guess what I'm asking is how do I run a shell script after the machine has booted up and the shared folder has been mounted? I've tried adding the command in Vagrantfile but that didn't work, also tried with an Upstart script but that didn't work either :(

P.S. The VM is the default box coming with Vagrant, Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to achieve this is to use a shell provisioner, with the run: always option, so that it is ran on every vagrant up:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "cd /vagrant && bundle exec jekyll serve --watch -P 4567 --force_polling&"
```